# Как взять стили при помощи jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, css, jquery

$('.block').outerWeight(); - это конструкцией jquery берёт стили из файла css, но когда я перезадаю блоку ширину jquery прописывает стили в HTML. Как получить стили из HTML или самые актуальные стили?

Answer (score 1):

Для вашего случая есть несколько вариантов:

```
$('.block').width();
```

либо

```
$('.block').css('width');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery и так берет стили из существующих на данный момент на странице.

**outerHeight()** и **outerWidth()** возвращает не значение свойства CSS **width** / **height**, а высоту / ширину содержимого элемента плюс отступы (border, padding, margin). Используйте методы **width()**, **height()**, или **css()**.